# How to get variables from content scripts in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to modify Google's [sample code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red.zip) for code injections. File `manifest.json` includes a background script:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

and I add a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["filter.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Now I want to call function `foo()` defined in `filter.js` when the user clicks the extension's button. I do this in `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'foo(testText);'
  });
});
```

where `foo()` is defined in `filter.js` as

```
function foo(test) {
  alert('Test: ' + String(test));
}
var testText = 'foo';
```

I can execute the function, but can't pass the `testText` variable. I get `VM3181:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: testText is not defined`.

I know I refer to the variable incorrectly, but how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `sendMessage` and `onMessage`, examples repurposed from Google:

In `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {greeting: "foo"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });
});
```

And in `filter.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "foo") {
            //your Foo function can be called
            sendResponse({farewell: "bar"});
        }
});
```